# Error when using KafkaSource in Flink: "The method setDeserializer(...) is not applicable for the arguments..."

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm trying to use the KafkaSource in Flink to read data from a Kafka topic instead of the deprecated FlinkKafkaConsumer. Here's my code:

```java
// Use KafkaSource instead of FlinkKafkaConsumer
DataStream<String> patientData = env.fromSource(
        KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
                .setGroupId("stroke-risk-group")
                .setTopics("patient-data-topic")
                .setProperties(properties)
                .setDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .setStartingOffsets(StartupMode.EARLIEST)
                .build(),
        "Kafka Source");
```

However, I'm getting an error that says:

"The method setDeserializer(KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema) in the type KafkaSourceBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (SimpleStringSchema)"

For a more in-depth view of the code:
https://github.com/IshaanAdarsh/healthcare-analytics/blob/main/icu-vsm/src/main/java/hes/cs63/CEPMonitor/StrokeRiskAlarm.java

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Can someone please explain why I'm getting this error and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```java
.setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
```

instead of `setDeserializer`. `setDeserializer` is appropriate when you are using a `KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema`, but in this case you are using a `DeserializationSchema`.

The difference is that a `KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema`  deserializes full Kafka record objects -- potentially using the record's key, headers, and other metadata for deserialization, in addition to the value part of the record -- while a `DeserializationSchema` only looks at the value.